# Using Holder and C-S to prove the radical inequality.

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, holder-inequality

For example$:$

For $x,y,z>0$ and $xy+yz+zx\geqq 3.$ Prove that$:$

$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{4x + 5y}} + \frac{y}{\sqrt{4y + 5z}} + \frac{z}{\sqrt{4z + 5x}} \geqq 1$$

It is easy and you can see my two proof [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2116749p15381905).

The main problem of this topic is as follow:

For inequality has form$:$ $$\frac{X}{\sqrt{A}}+\frac{Y}{\sqrt{B}}+\frac{Z}{\sqrt{C}} \geqq k$$

Using $\lceil$ **HOLDER!inequality** $\rfloor:$

$$\text{LHS} =\sqrt{\frac{(\frac{X}{\sqrt{A}}+\frac{Y}{\sqrt{B}}+\frac{Z}{\sqrt{C}} )^2 (AXW_1^3 +BYW_2^3 +CZW_3^3)}{AXW_1^3 +BYW_2^3 +CZW_3^3}} \geqq \sqrt{\frac{(W_1 X +W_2 Y+W_3 Z)^3}{AXW_1^3 +BYW_2^3 +CZW_3^3}}$$

Our problem become $$(W_1 X +W_2 Y+W_3 Z)^3 \geqq k^2 (AXW_1^3 +BYW_2^3 +CZW_3^3) \,\, -------(1)$$

But to choose $W_1,\,W_2,\,W_3$ is not ussualy easy as the first example. I have no idea to find it$,$ what is your idea$?$

Mr Liu Qian Bao use [agl2012](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1827454) program to find out it!

In the opposite case$,$ $$\frac{X}{\sqrt{A}}+\frac{Y}{\sqrt{B}}+\frac{Z}{\sqrt{C}} \leqq k$$

Using $\lceil$ **Cauchy-Schwarz!inequality** $\rfloor:$ $$(W_1 +W_2 +W_3) (\frac{X^2}{W_1 A}+\frac{Y^2}{W_2 B} +\frac{Z^2}{W_3 C}) \geqq (\frac{X}{\sqrt{A}}+\frac{Y}{\sqrt{B}}+\frac{Z}{\sqrt{C}})^2$$

Neeed to prove$:$ $$k^2 \geqq (W_1 +W_2 +W_3) (\frac{X^2}{W_1 A}+\frac{Y^2}{W_2 B} +\frac{Z^2}{W_3 C})$$

We have the same problem is find $W_1,\,W_2,\,W_3$$?$

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think,  this algorithm just does not exist . Sometimes we need to use the gland inside the skull.

Comment: In the link, Mr Baoqian Liu's first post, the last line.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg  I found you applied Holder for many problems of inequalities by constructing the terms (which is difficult).

Comment: @River Li  What do you mean? I think my form of using Holder gives a possibility to use Holder. I wrote it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/holder-inequality/info  The form with $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}+...=1$ is a very bad, I think.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg  I mean there may be some 'rule' to design/construct the terms, as you shown in some problems of inequalities.

Comment: The unique rule here is to save the equality case occurring. The rest is open for thinking.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg , I wish to know your C-S and Holder, teach me, huh ?

Comment: Does anyone knows the name of the book written by Liu Qian Bao